# I need help making Pokemon types show up when building a randomizer using a Pokemon API in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, fetch-api

I'm still pretty new to programming and I'm building a random Pokemon generator in JavaScript using a Pokemon API, I'm having trouble making the Pokemon type show up in a fetch request because it is nestled in an array in the API.

I can fetch the `name`, `id`, and `base experience` values just fine, because they are listed as their own individual values within the API, but types show up as `[object Object]` because they are listed in an array and I'm not quite sure how to retrieve them. Here is my code and a link the the [API I'm using](https://pokeapi.co/)

```js
const name = document.getElementById('name')
const id = document.getElementById('id')
const type = document.getElementById('type')
const baseexperience = document.getElementById('baseexperience')
const button = document.querySelector('.myButton');

button.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
  e.preventDefault()
  const randomPokemon = Math.ceil(Math.random() * 1017)
  fetch(`https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/${randomPokemon}`)
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(pokemon => {
      console.log(pokemon)
      name.innerHTML = pokemon['name']
      id.innerHTML = pokemon['id']
      type.innerHTML = pokemon['types']
      baseexperience.innerHTML = pokemon['base_experience']

    })

})
```

```html
<body>

  <div id="name"></div>
  <div id="id"></div>
  <div id="type"></div>
  <div id="baseexperience"></div>

  <button class="myButton">Catch 'em all</button>
</body>
```

Comment: `type.innerText = pokemon.types.map(t => t.type.name).join(', ')` - by the way you should use `innerText` and not `innerHTML`, you don't get HTML from the API so there is no reason to allow formatted and potentially dangerous data!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `types` property is an array of objects, for example:

```
"types": [
    {
        "slot": 1,
        "type": {
            "name": "bug",
            "url": "https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/type/7/"
        }
    },
    {
        "slot": 2,
        "type": {
            "name": "steel",
            "url": "https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/type/9/"
        }
    }
]
```

JavaScript has no *default* way of representing this data as a string, other than something like `[object Object],[object Object]`.  You'd need to indicate what you want to display.

For example, if you want to display the type names as a comma-separated list, you can `.map()` over that array to project it to a list of strings, and then `.join()` those strings by a comma.  Something like this:

```
type.innerHTML = pokemon['types'].map(type => type.type.name).join(', ')
```

**Edit:** It appears that it can display at least an array of strings, and would insert a comma automatically:

```
type.innerHTML = pokemon['types'].map(type => type.type.name)
```

Though you could still use `.join()` to include a space after the comma for readability of course.  You could also modify the logic to display them as `<li>` elements in a `<ul>`, etc.

Answer (score -1):

Try this instead:

```
<script>
    const name = document.getElementById('name')
    const id = document.getElementById('id')
    const type = document.getElementById('type')
    const baseexperience = document.getElementById('baseexperience')
    const button = document.querySelector('.myButton');

    button.addEventListener('click', (e) => {

        const randomPokemon = Math.ceil(Math.random() * 1017)

        fetch(`https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/${randomPokemon}`)
            .then(response => response.json())
            .then(pokemon => {
                let Totaltypes = pokemon.types.map(type => type.type.name)
                name.innerHTML = pokemon.name
                id.innerHTML = pokemon.id
                type.innerHTML = Totaltypes
                baseexperience.innerHTML = pokemon.base_experience

            })

    })


</script>
```

You was trying to print two objects. With Totaltypes you save every type's name in a string and the string value.